# AngularJS : display param from a service in a view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-services

How can I build a service that can be called from everywhere I need with a custom param.

I have this code:

```
.service('loadingService', function($ionicLoading) {
    this.showLoading=function(textToBeDisplayed){
        $ionicLoading.show({
          noBackdrop: false,
          templateUrl: 'templates/loading-template.html'
        });
    };
    this.hideLoading=function(){
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    };  
});
```

View: (loading-template.html)

```
<div>{{textToBeDisplayed}}<ion-spinner icon="ios"/></div>
```

Controller:

```
loadingService.showLoading('loading all data');
```

Loading is displayed but "textToBeDisplayed" is not visible in the view.
Any ideeas ?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to create a modal? you can use modal Service.

Comment: I think you need to set the textToBeDisplayed on that scope being used. I'm not familiar with $ionicLoading but the documentation mentions a scope option...

Comment: it's working if I move all the code in my controller, define have a $scope.textToBeDisplayed  and add  "scope=$scope" to $ionicLoading . But I wanted to have something generic..loadingService.showLoading('loading all data');

Comment: because I don't want to add everywhere in my app, in all controller all this code

Comment: you can add it to `$rootScope`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your service should use `template` as you are passing template content

```
.service('loadingService', function($ionicLoading) {
    this.showLoading=function(textToBeDisplayed){
        $ionicLoading.show({
          noBackdrop: false,
          template: '<div>'+textToBeDisplayed+'<ion-spinner icon="ios"/></div>'
        });
    };
    this.hideLoading=function(){
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    };  
});
```

Comment: this is a good solution even if I wanted to have template in a separate html file :) .. until I find a better solution I will use this

Comment: This is a better specific solution for this case.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this:

```
.service('loadingService', function($rootScope) {
    return function(textToBeDisplayed) {
        $rootScope.textToBeDisplayed = textToBeDisplayed;
        //put whatever else you want here.
    }
});
```

call it like this in your controller:

```
loadingService('someText');
```

Put this binding in your HTML:

```
{{textToBeDisplayed}}
```

Don't forget to inject the service into any controller you need to access it from.

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/n1LdDAG8k9C1JC7qBDyM?p=preview

Comment: I'm don't know if is a good practice to add many things on rootScope :) is there any way to clean that var from rootscope when I hide the loading ?